# How do I monitor system parameters like memory, CPU and disks on windows systems via SNMP?

Tags: snmp, cpu-usage

I want to monitor system parameters like CPU load, CPU Idle time on windows system via SNMP. Does HOST-RESOURCES-MIB can handle this?

Comment: what model your server ?

Comment: Its a generic server with intel processor, using windows server 2012.

Answer (score 3):

In HOST-RESOURCES-MIB, you will be able to find the entry for the CPU usage. See http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.html for the details of this MIB and his entries.

It appears there is an entry for the disks and memory (in storage) and partitions too.

You can use snmpwalk or a MIB Browser to navigate in the MIB of your server.

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB :    1.3.6.1.2.1.25
```

For the memory,

Comment: Would you also know if i can get the cpu utilization? Or cpu idle time?

Comment: If you look at the details of host-ressource it seems there is not the cpu idle time. For that you must prefer using NRPE to supervise your windows environment.

Comment: Your welcome, if the answer is ok you can  mark  it as answered. Good luck :)